# Elvis operator ?. strangely doesn't compile in obvious cases

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, roslyn, c#-6.0

This static method compiles:

```
public static void Foo<TValue>(Func<TValue> factory = null)
{
    factory?.Invoke();
}
```

And why wouldn't it? This one, however, doesn't:

```
public static void Foo<TValue>(Func<TValue> factory = null)
{
    var x = factory?.Invoke();
}
```

Using the return value seems to make a difference:

[image]

Of course, the operator `?.` isn't applied to an operand of type `TValue`, but to one of type `Func<TValue>`, which is why it works when not using the expression value.

The non-generic case works just fine:

```
public static void Bar(Func<String> factory = null)
{
    var x = factory?.Invoke();
}
```

Comment: For searchability's sake, that's a "null-conditional operator".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just think through what type `factory?.Invoke();` should resolve to.  (An exercise you'd need to do if you didn't use `var` here.)  What type should it be?

To determine what type it needs to be think through how the value is computed.  If the delegate is not null you need to invoke it and resolve the operation to a `TValue`, which is whatever the delegate returns.  But if the delegate is `null` that expression, `factory?.Invoke();`, needs to resolve to null, so `TValue`, needs to be a nullable type.  So what if `TValue` isn't nullable, if it's not, then that expression can't be of type `TValue`, but then what *should* it be?

Comment: `?.` in general does work with non-nullable types. `Func<int> f = null; var i = f?.Invoke();` is just peachy and gives `i` type `int?`. It's just that this cannot work in generics. There is no type that resolves as "maybe `T?`, maybe `T`".

Comment: @hvd Indedd, that's why I worded the question the way that I did.  You need to answer the question of what type `factory?.Invoke();` resolves to.  If you *know* it's a non-nullable type, you know that expression can resolve to `TValue?`, but as it is, you can't possibly know what type it resolves to, and so obviously neither can the compiler.

Answer (score 7):

Try adding `where TValue: class` to make sure `TValue` can be `null`:

```
static void Foo<TValue>(Func<TValue> factory = null) where TValue: class
```

In that case, compiler can deduce type of `x` as `TValue` and assign `null` to it when needed (e.g. in the case `factory == null`).

Or try

```
static void Foo<TValue>(Func<TValue> factory = null) where TValue: struct
```

In that case, the deduced type would be `TValue?`. (Credit goes to **@hvd**.)